# Angular 5: Unable to center or style location of MatDialog box

Tags: html, css, angular, dialog

I have a simple page with a button that should open a MatDialog box. Unfortunately, it defaults to being left aligned on the page, but I want it centered on the webpage.

Here is the HTML for app.component.html:

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="text-align: center; margin-top: 100px">
        <button (click)="popUp()">Pop Up</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the popUp function in app.component.ts:

```
popUp() {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(PopUpComponent, {
      disableClose: false,
      hasBackdrop: true,
      backdropClass: '',
      width: '250px',
      height: '',
      position: {
        top: '',
        bottom: '',
        left: '',
        right: ''
      }
    });
  }
```

And here is the HTML for the popupcomponent class:

```
<div card-body style="text-align: center">
  <h1>Pop Up</h1>
  <div class="summary-table-wrapper">
    <ag-grid-angular (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)">
    </ag-grid-angular>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I center the PopUp dialog box in the direct middle of my webpage? I have tried almost everything.

Comment: did you try position: absolute on your pop up ?

Comment: Would I put it in the component itself, or the dialogRef?

Comment: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/11912